"Contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" - but all factors do have two or more levels?
I have successfully used the ClusterBootstrap package in R in the past to perform hierarchical bootstrapping. I am now attempting to apply it to a new data set, and am receiving an error when using the clusbootglm function to create a glm using the predictors Pain and Drug on P7_Weight which using Dam_Number (the litter ID) to control for litter.
Here is the dput to recreate the data set in question:
library(tidyverse)
library(ClusterBootstrap)

structure(list(Dam_Number = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), levels = 
c("6861", 
"6867", "6868", "6870", "7273", "7274", "7275", "7276", "7300", 
"7303", "7304"), class = "factor"), Pain_Drug = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = 
c("Sham_Saline", 
"CCI_Oxy", "CCI_Saline", "Sham_Oxy"), class = "factor"), Pain = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Sham", 
"CCI"), class = "factor"), Drug = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Saline", "Oxy"), 
class = "factor"), 
Sex = c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), Pup_Number = 
c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), P7_Weight 
= c(14.2, 
14.1, 14.3, 14, 13, 14.1, 14.1, 12.9, 13.6, 12.4, 14, 11.5, 
12, 11, 11.6, 11.4, 8.7, 13.5, 10, 11.7, 10.9, 11.2, 11.3, 
8.9, 11, 10.1, 10.8, 10, 16.5, 16.6, 14.5, 16.3, 14.9, 17.2, 
15.8, 16.2, 15.7, 15.2, 15.4, 15.7, 16.3, 16.2, 16.3, 15.2, 
16.4, 14.8, 15.2, 16.1, 14.8, 15.3, 14.6, 16, 15.9, 13.2, 
15.2, 14.8, 14.8, 14.4, 13.2, 15.4, 12.3, 10.6, 11.5, 10, 
12.8, 12.2, 12.7, 10.8, 10.8, 9.2, 10, 10, 10, 8.5, 10, 13.9, 
16.5, 13, 16.3, 16.6, 13.8, 12.4, 14.3, 13.5, 15.2, 14.6, 
13.1, 14, 15.8, 13.6, 11.7, 16, 14.1, 16.1, 14.2, 15.6, 16.3, 
16, 14.5, 15.3, 15.5, 14.7, 13.7, 14.6, 14.1, 15.3, 14.6, 
14.5, 13.1, 13.1, 14.2, 13.4, 12.1, 13.8, 13.6, 15.1, 13.2, 
15, 15.7, 14.4, 14.7, 13.7, 13.5, 11.7, 12.3, 13.3, 10, 12.9, 
12.9, 10, 10, 12.4, 11.3, 11.4, 13.2, 11.2, 12.7, 11.1, 9.5, 
10), Ref = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -140L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

When I run the clusbootglm function as below:
model_weight <- clusbootglm(P7_Weight ~ Pain*Drug, data = weights, clusterid = Dam_Number, family = gaussian, B = 5000, confint.level = 0.95, n.cores = 1)

It returns the following error (with traceback included):
'Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
11.stop("contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels")
10.`contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])
9.model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts)
8.model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
7.glm(model, family = family, data = data[obs, ])
6.coef(glm(model, family = family, data = data[obs, ]))
5.doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
4.tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
3.tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
2.tryCatch(coef(glm(model, family = family, data = data[obs, ])),warning = function(x) rep(as.numeric(NA), p))
1.clusbootglm(P7_Weight ~ Pain * Drug, data = weights, clusterid = Dam_Number, family = gaussian, B = 5000, confint.level = 0.95, n.cores = 1)'

There is a lot of discussion on the site about this error, but all questions return to the idea that there are NAs or constant variables in the data set. There was an excellent function provided in this post to attempt to debug this error. My data set passes this debug with flying colors, stating that all predictors have greater than 2 levels:
'$nlevels
Dam_Number  Pain_Drug       Pain       Drug        Sex 
        11          4          2          2          2 

$levels
$levels$Dam_Number
 [1] "6861" "6867" "6868" "6870" "7273" "7274" "7275" "7276" "7300" "7303" "7304"

$levels$Pain_Drug
[1] "Sham_Saline" "CCI_Oxy"     "CCI_Saline"  "Sham_Oxy"   

$levels$Pain
[1] "Sham" "CCI" 

$levels$Drug
[1] "Saline" "Oxy"   

$levels$Sex
[1] "F" "M"'

Interestingly, if I use a combined variable (Pain_Drug) which has 4 levels, the code runs no problem.
model_weight <- clusbootglm(P7_Weight ~ Pain_Drug, data = weights, clusterid = Dam_Number, family = gaussian, B = 5000, confint.level = 0.95, n.cores = 1)

It seems there is a problem with the interaction aspect.

I think the issue is that your clusters don't have any variation in the factors, so some bootstrap samples end up with one of the factors not having any variation at all.  I don't know the procedure well enough to suggest a way to work around this.

That usually appears as a different error where it lists the number of NA bootstrap samples. This is a slightly smaller sample than I have used previously, so maybe that could be the case, but if I try to run the model with EITHER Pain or Drug instead of the interaction or the combined variable, it still returns the same error.

so your main effects model works Pain+Drug but not the interaction model Pain*Drug?

When you bootstrap you choose at random from your variables and this might miss some of the levels. Imagine you have 2 levels and all sampled values are of the same category. Then you will get that error (It happened to me more than once.)

If you use options(error = recover), then R will stop at the point where the error is generated.  When I did that it happened on bootstrap sample 162.  Presumably you'll get a different stopping point with a different random seed.  You can look at the variables in the clusbootglm call at that point.  (I have n.cores == 1, which makes debugging easier.)  Look at data[obs, ].

Looks to me as though the author of ClusterBootstrap missed the possibility of this error happening.  It would be an easy fix to the code:  it already catches warnings, just let it catch errors as well.

The function clusbootglm handles numeric input:
library(tidyverse)
library(ClusterBootstrap)

weights <- weights |> 
  mutate(Sex = as.factor(Sex)) |> 
  mutate(across(-Dam_Number, ~as.numeric(.))) |> 
  select(Dam_Number, Pain, Drug, P7_Weight)

model_weight <- clusbootglm(P7_Weight ~ Pain*Drug, data = weights, 
                            clusterid = Dam_Number, family = gaussian, B = 5000, confint.level = 0.95, n.cores = 1)


That's probably an equivalent model, but how do the coefficients compare?  If I set B = 100 I get both models to succeed, but the parametrizations are completely different.

This seems to have fixed the problem! Not sure why it is requiring numeric now, as I am fairly certain I have used factors in the past... But it is working! Thank you,

@HannahHarder:  it runs, but it gives different answers than your original code was asking for.  Do you know how to convert one to the other?

Can you clarify what you mean by it gives different answers? Did you include set.seed in your code to control for randomness? It appears normal to me

@HannahHarder:  it fits a model with different parameter names and meanings.  If I run with set.seed(1) and B=100, both versions work.  Yours has model_weight$lm.coefs with names (Intercept)         PainCCI         DrugOxy PainCCI:DrugOxy and values 13.9464286      -1.7775397      -0.8275097       3.8652874.  The numeric version has names (Intercept)        Pain        Drug   Pain:Drug and values 20.416765   -5.642827   -4.692797    3.865287 .  As I said above, I think that's an equivalent model, but a different parametrization.

Hmm @user2554330 I hadn't noticed that. Yes, I am definitely used to the first type of coefficients. I am not sure how to interpret the second type.
